# What does Retry mean in context of Java Couchbase SDK?

Tags: java, spring, couchbase, couchbase-java-api, retry-logic

I am using Java couchbase sdk in my application. While setting up the [DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.0.0/com/couchbase/client/java/env/DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.html), I came across the property [RetryStrategy](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-core-io-1.4.8/com/couchbase/client/core/retry/RetryStrategy.html?is-external=true). Now I am using the default configuration for which the retry strategy is **BestEffortRetryStrategy**. According to documentation

```
BestEffortRetryStrategy will retry the operation until it either succeeds or the maximum request lifetime is reached
```

By default the maximum request lifetime is 75 seconds.

Now what i what i want to understand here is what does retry mean here. Does retry mean retrying the request whenever an exception occurs or does it mean it will retry to allocate this request to some node to process the request in case it can't and it will keep retrying for 75 seconds?

I am looking at my application logs for different exceptions to understand this and I could see that [TemporaryFailureException](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.1.2/index.html?com/couchbase/client/java/error/TemporaryFailureException.html) wasn't retried and i could also see that in some instances [RequestCancelledException](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-core-io-1.5.3/com/couchbase/client/core/RequestCancelledException.html) was being thrown after 75 seconds. Is it fair to assume that couchbase retries a request to assign it to node to process it and not actually retries on any exception once it makes it to the node that will process this request?

StackTrace for TemporaryFailureException-

````
stackTrace: com.couchbase.client.java.error.TemporaryFailureException: null
    at com.couchbase.client.java.bucket.api.Mutate$2$1.call(Mutate.java:246)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.bucket.api.Mutate$2$1.call(Mutate.java:220)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:235)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:101)
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onCompleted(AsyncSubject.java:103)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.completeResponse(AbstractGenericHandler.java:508)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.access$000(AbstractGenericHandler.java:86)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler$1.call(AbstractGenericHandler.java:526)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.core.message.kv.UpsertResponse.class
    at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73)
    ... 21 common frames omitted```
````

Answer (score 0):

BestEffortRetryStrategy should retry until the the request is cancelled by the timeout.
FailFastRetryStrategy should not retry. It should fail immediately.

If you have a TemporaryFailureException and have BestEffortRetryStrategy, that should have been retried. If you had one that was not retried can you share the stacktrace?

- Mike

Comment: Updated the question with the stack trace.